# Export in glTF format in StandardCyborgFusion

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcframework

I am using StandardCyborgFusion and StandardCyborgUI to create 3D scan of object in their example app. In `SCScene` there is method called `writeToGLTFAtPath` but doesn't seem to be working. It does create a gLTF file but its corrupt and invalid. Is there any alternative way to address this issue. Like convert SCNNode to glTF or usdz file to glTF converter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0wod.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb9kd.png)

I tried exporting the SCNNode in `.scn` format and also export in `.usdz` that work perfectly. But the given method in SDK doesn't seem to be working. Its also been reported by many developer but doesn't seems to be addressed by anyone yet. [LINK](https://github.com/StandardCyborg/StandardCyborgCocoa/issues/28).

Is there any other way we can do this?